# Меню для рубрикации css

Tags: меню, html, css

На гл. стр #Хэшкода [вот такое меню](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWREV.png).
Кто знает как должен выглядеть css?
HTML есть.

```
<div class="tabsA">
<a href="/?index_sort=текущие" class="on" title="недавно обновленные">текущие</a><a href="/?index_sort=горячие" title="наиболее активные в последние 24 часа">горячие</a><a href="/?index_sort=недельные" title="наиболее активные в последнюю неделю">неделя</a><a href="/?index_sort=месячные" title="наиболее активные в последний месяц">месяц</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Откройте браузер Хром, наведите курсор мыши на любой элемент на странице, правым щелчком мыши откройте контекстное меню, выберите пункт «Inspect element» — выскочит дополнительное окно и в правой части будет виден CSS этого элемента.

Comment: Артур, помоги пожалуйста. Ничего не получается, сколько пытался

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы можете просматривать исходный код `html` страницы, что Вы успешно продемонстрировали, для Вас не составит труда найти в этом исходном коде теги `<link>`, понять, какие из них подключают `css`, подставить значение атрибута `href` в адресную строку и посмотреть, какие стили.

Comment: Замучаешься по link -ам лазить

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLVpP/